# Transact-SQL: how to update part of string

Tags: sql-server, cursor, substring

I need to update some records in SQL Server. In fact I need to remove part of a string and update the same record. I've done the following:

```
USE [BRAZIL]

DECLARE @PRODUCTDESCRIPTION nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @MERDA nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @CONTADOR Int;

DECLARE C CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR 
     SELECT DISTINCT Id 
     FROM ProductVariant

OPEN C

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @CONTADOR

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @PRODUCTDESCRIPTION = (SELECT Description 
                               FROM ProductVariant 
                               WHERE ID = @CONTADOR );  

    IF CHARINDEX('This Should be Removed', @PRODUCTDESCRIPTION) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @MER = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, 0, CHARINDEX('This Should be Removed', @PRODUCTDESCRIPTION)));

        UPDATE ProductVariant
        SET Description = @MER
    END

    SET @PRODUCTDESCRIPTION = '';

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @CONTADOR
END

CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```

If there is no record that satisfies the pattern `'This Should be Removed'` nothing happens on table. This is great. But if there is only one record that has `'This Should be Removed'` all the others records are updated with the same value of this one.

Can anybody help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single statement, without using a cursor:

```
UPDATE ProductVariant
SET Description = REPLACE(Description, 'This Should be Removed', '')
```

The `REPLACE` function looks for 'This Should be Removed', and if found will replace it with a blank string. If a description doesn't contain 'This Should be Removed', the description will not be changed.

Your current code is updating every record because your update statement does not have a where clause:

```
UPDATE ProductVariant
SET Description = @MER
```

You would need to add `WHERE Id = @CONTADOR`, but its much better to do it in a single statement. Your current code is actually updating the entire table on every iteration of the while loop, and setting the description column for the entire table to the description of the current Id in the while loop.

The first and probably most important thing to understand when programming for databases is that you want to work on the entire set of rows, rather than process each row individually.